# How to show that you pass ownership of the pointer

Tags: c++, qt, c++03

First, I know about unique_ptr and share_ptr, but **I'm not using C++11** and thus I can't use them.

Every possible research from google returns a solution using those two smart pointers. I would like one without.

I need to pass ownership of a pointer to another class through the constructor.

```
PointerToPass* myPointer = new PointerToPass();
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass(myPointer);
```

So I could use raw pointers but I read everywhere that I should avoid it.

Using a reference is not an option.

I could use a smart pointer from Qt to show that I pass ownership like so:

```
QScopedPointer<PointerToPass> myPointer(new PointerToPass());
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass(myPointer.take());
```

This option clearly shows that the pointer is passed and that the ownership is given to myClass even if it's still using raw pointers.

Is there a better way to convey this idea?

It would be even better if it could be seen in the MyClass constructor signature.

Comment: You shouldn't use `new` from a copy of `take`. `take` resets the scoped ptr to null.

Comment: Yes, but in this scope I don't use myPointer anymore. It is only used in MyClass once it's passed.

Comment: Why not `new MyClass(new PointerToPass());`? Or for that matter, if the pointer type takes no arguments, just let `MyClass` ctor allocate it.

Comment: Yes I could. It's just that in the real code, I have to pass 3 parameters to PointerToPass so it becomes a huge mess.

Comment: @JamesRoot I might be wrong but variadic constructors are only possible with C++11. I explicitely said I'm not using it.

Comment: @dyesdyes Right, I forgot. Still, if `MyClass` owns `PointerToPass`, it makes the most sense for `MyClass` to completely manage it.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow mistook that as copying the pointer contents and then leaking it. My bad. Ideally, `myClass` wouldn't have to be a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about clear indication pointer is not to be used outside?

```
class myClass {
    public: myClass(PointerToPass*& p): _p(p) {
        p = nullptr;
    }

    public: ~myClass() {
        delete _p;
    }

    private: PointerToPass* _p;
};

PointerToPass* myPointer = new PointerToPass();

MyClass* myClass = new MyClass(myPointer);
std::cout << myPointer << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t) has some advice about this and suggest you use `owner` from the [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/) (GSL) to annotate raw pointers.

```
template <class T>
using owner = T;
```

This is just a typedef of `owner<T>` to `T`. It serves only as annotation and would work for your constructor argument. If this syntax wasn't C++11.

We could use a similar idea instead though.

```
template<typename T>
struct owner
{
    typedef T pointer;
};

MyClass(owner<PointerToPass*>::pointer p)
{
    // ...
}
```

Similar to the technique in the guidelines, this doesn't actually enforce anything. It does annotate the code to make the ownership sematics clearer though.